# Laravel firstOrNew overwriting all entries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having problems with the firstOrNew() method. Please see my method below.

```
public function updateUnique($attributeId, $data)
{
    $attribute = \App\Clients\Attribute::firstOrNew(
        [
        'mem_id' => $data->lead_id, 
        'attribute_id' => $attributeId, 
        'type' => $this->updateType($data->pk)
        ] );

    $attribute->mem_id = $data->lead_id;
    $attribute->type = $this->updateType($data->pk);
    $attribute->attribute_id = $attributeId;
    $attribute->attribute = $data->value;

    $attribute->save();
}
```

This worked absolutely fine until I added the property `public $primaryKey = "mem_id";` on the model Attribute.

All entries in the database are updated if "first". The 'new' aspect works ok.

As soon as I remove that it works. I'd like to try and understand what's going on?

Comment: If you have `$primaryKey = 'mem_id'` and it is NOT auto incrementing, then you need to also provide `public $incrementing = false;` on your Attribute model too - @see the [Source Code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L71)

Comment: Thanks @ash I didn't realise that. However it didn't solve the issue? So confused

Comment: Do you have `mem_id` inside the `$fillable` property on `Attribute`?